# Is there any SCN (System Change Number) like in SQL that can be replicated in Redis Database?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I need to find out whether a data has been modified in a row, so that next time when it gets the value it knows that this particular row has been modified in Redis Database? Somewhat like an SCN value in Sql but in Redis database. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Redis does not expose a last modification timestamp for keys, you can easily achieve what you are looking for by storing that information on different keys, (possibly) named after the keys you are tracking: for every modification of the key named *key*, for example, you would also immediately set the key named *key_modified_on* with the current timestamp.

To make the operation transaction-like, you could use a [MULTI/EXEC transaction](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Transactions.html#and-in-stackexchangeredis) (or even a Lua script, if needed):

```cs
var transaction = database.CreateTransaction();
transaction.StringSetAsync("mykey", "myvalue");
transaction.StringSetAsync("mykey_modified_on", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O"));
await transaction.ExecuteAsync();
```

With that being said, Redis exposes an *idle time* (not requested by read or write operations) for each key through the `OBJECT` command, provided (according to the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/object)) `maxmemory-policy` is set to an LRU policy or `noeviction` and `maxmemory` is set. In that case, you can just use the `KeyIdleTimeAsync()` method:

```cs
var idleTime = await database.KeyIdleTimeAsync("mykey");
```